# Callback with regex in coffeescript, javascript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have a function:

```
    validatorsString.replace(/([\w_$]+)\(([\w_$,]+)\)/g, (all, fn, args) ->
      args = args.split ','
      if typeof validatorsObject[fn] is 'function'
        res = validatorsObject[fn].apply validatorsObject, args
        if res == false
          formBox.addError obj, "Pole musi byc takie"
          return false
          #obj.css "background-color", "red"
    )
```

I want to do something if everything is good. Above function is calling validators (1,3,10) and I want to send ajax if every validator returned true. How to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a "global state"

```
isValid = true

validatorsString.replace(/([\w_$]+)\(([\w_$,]+)\)/g, (all, fn, args) ->
  return unless isValid # short-circuit if we detected an error already
  args = args.split ','
  if typeof validatorsObject[fn] is 'function'
    res = validatorsObject[fn].apply validatorsObject, args
    isValid = false unless res

unless isValid
  formBox.addError obj, "Pole musi byc takie"
  #obj.css "background-color", "red"
  return false

$.post "stuff"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you will keep it cleaner in the future, if you keep the logic of running the validators and updating the view in separate functions. Then, you can write it like this:

```
isValid = (validationString) ->
  re = /([\w_$]+)\(([\w_$,]+)\)/g
  while match = re.exec(validationString)
    [fn, args] = [match[1], match[2].split(',')]
    if _(validatorsObject[fn]).isFunction() and not validatorsObject[fn].apply validatorsObject, args
      return false
  true

unless isValid(validationString)
  formBox.addError obj, "Pole musi byc takie"
```

I've used underscore.js for checking the type of the validator, because I believe that `typeof` check like the one in your code fails on Android 2.3 stock browser. Some food for thought.

Comment: Didn't check but looks better. Thanks.